# Warning when passing arguments to a GUIDE GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to pass arguments to a GUIDE generated GUI.  This works but throws a Warning.

```
inputTest('Passed In String')
```

> Warning: The input to STR2FUNC "Passed In String" is not a valid
>   function name. This will generate an error in a future release.

I know I have passed arguments to GUIDE GUIs in the past and I don't recall ever seeing this warning message before.  However, I am relatively new to Matlab 2016b so something may have changed that I am not aware of.  I didn't find anything in the documentation.

The warning occurs in the "initialization code - DO NOT EDIT" auto generated section and only happens when passing in an optional argument.

Is this a bug in 2016b or have I missed something?

Minimal Example below.  It is a simple GUI with only a single Edit box.

```
function varargout = inputTest(varargin)
% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @inputTest_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @inputTest_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1}); % WARNING OCCURS HERE
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

function inputTest_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
% Fill the box if the string is passed in.
if nargin == 4
    handles.edit1.String = varargin{1};
else
    handles.edit1.String = 'Nothing Passed In';
end   
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = inputTest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;

function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default GUIDE GUI behavior is explained in the autogenerated inline documentation:

```
% ASDF MATLAB code for asdf.fig
%      ASDF, by itself, creates a new ASDF or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = ASDF returns the handle to a new ASDF or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      ASDF('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in ASDF.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      ASDF('Property','Value',...) creates a new ASDF or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before asdf_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to asdf_OpeningFcn via varargin.
```

The syntax you're attempting to use is the syntax reserved for calling callbacks that are local to your GUI, which is why it's using a `str2func` call on the first input. Either remove the `str2func` call or change your input syntax to accept a separate output than what GUIDE is designed for.

Comment: That reminded me of how I worked around the issue before.  I dug up one of my older GUIDE based GUIs to confirm.  In the past my input to a GUI was a cell array.  Doing it that way will bypass the `str2fun` call since it is not a `char` & the input will still show up as varargin{1} in the OpeningFcn for use as you see fit.